# How to get all Azure Resources without tags in a Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group, azure-devtest-labs

In my Azure dev/test lab (DTL), there are many resources which were not tagged. How can I get a list of all untagged resources under DTL/resource group?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This [link](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2017/7/15/powershell-for-assigning-querying-tags-in-azure) has the solution for this question. It beautifully explains assigning and querying tags using powershell.

$resourceGroupName = 'InternalReportingRGDev'

$azureRGInfo = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName
foreach ($item in $azureRGInfo)

{

Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameEquals $item.ResourceGroupName | ForEach-Object {Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $PSItem.ResourceId -Tag $item.Tags -Force }

}

Comment: PowerShell script has invalid syntax, not good for the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple PowerShell loop to get untagged resources.

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource
foreach($resource in $resources)
{
    if ($resource.Tags -eq $null)
    {
        echo $resource.Name, $resource.ResourceType
    }
}
```

Other ways to query this information and also set tags programmatically or as part of resource deployments are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags).

If you want to avoid the situation of ending up with untagged resources, you could enforce a [customized policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-policy) that all resources should have a value for a particular tag.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the idiomatic PowerShell to supplement @huysmania's answer which is expressed in procedural language mindset (and updated for the new PowerShell Az cmdlets):

```
Get-AzResource | Where-Object Tags -eq $null | Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceType
```

and the terse (alias) form:

```
Get-AzResource | ? Tags -eq $null | select Name, ResourceType
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually just run this command to output a table of untagged resources using [`Get-AzResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-3.7.0). It filters Azure resources with tags that are `$null` *or* empty using [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7).

```
Get-AzResource `
    | Where-Object {$null -eq $_.Tags -or $_.Tags.Count -eq 0} `
    | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

If you want to list untagged resources for a specific *resource group*, you can just add the `-ResourceGroupName` switch to `Get-AzResource`.

```
$resourceGroupName = "My Resource Group"

Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    | Where-Object {$null -eq $_.Tags -or $_.Tags.Count -eq 0} `
    | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**Note:** The above uses the newer [Azure PowerShell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.7.0), which is replacement for `AzureRM`.

Answer (score 0):

<#Bellow is PowerShell script to locate untagged resources - 
you may change the script out put as per your requirement.
Hope must be helpful. Thanks!#>

```
Write-Host "List all resource where Tag value is not Set"
Write-Host "********************************************"
#Fetch all resource details
$resources=get-AzureRmResource
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    $tagcount=(get-AzureRmResource | where-object {$_.Name -match $resource.Name}).Tags.count
    if($tagcount -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "Resource Name - "$resource.Name
        Write-Host "Resource Type and RG Name : " $resource.resourcetype " & " $resource.resourcegroupname "`n"
    }
 }
```

Comment: `$resource` already has the tag member. No need for `$tagcount=(get-AzureRmResource | where-object {$_.Name -match $resource.Name}).Tags.count`. This is innefficient and slow because it has to search every resource to find the tag for the current resource. You can get the count simply with `$tagcount = $resource.Tags.Count`.